# What is the best way to inject different robots.txt into war file based on target?

Tags: maven, gitlab-ci, robots.txt

I'd like to include a robots.txt file into a WAR file but use a different version based on the destination (e.g. sandbox or production).

What is the best way to achieve this with maven?   My first thought it is

1. Create two different robots.txt in the source code; one called produdction.robots.txt and another called sandbox.robots.txt
2. Use https://coderplus.github.io/copy-rename-maven-plugin/rename-mojo.html to rename the appropriate file to robots.txt during the build process
3. use maven war configuration to exclude the other file

Is there a more elegant way?  Note: we're using Gitlab CI/CD though I don't think that is too pertinent, assuming it is best to keep this process solely within the maven build cycle.

Thanks!